# Java web service client

Tags: java, web-services, unix, webservices-client

I have created a stand-alone Java web service client using stub class files and it works fine when it is run from Eclipse.

When I moved the client and class files from stub to a unix box where it is supposed to run from, I am facing an issue (by the way JDK on unix OS is: java version "1.6.0_07")

When I compile my Java client it compiles with warnings such as:
/signer/SignServ.class: major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.

Note: SignServ.class is stub class file

When I try to  "execute" my client Class file I am getting the error message:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/signer/EService : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Note: EService is also stub class

I understand the JDK/JRE version on UNIX box is lower than Java version on which stub class were compiled and this mismatch is throwing the error.

Problem is that I cannot upgrade JDK/JRE on UNIX box since it is controlled environment and policy bound.

Is there a way to get around this issue whist using stand alone java client? If not java client, any other alternative where I don't need to use stub class files?

Little more info - The webservice I am trying to invoke provide digital signature of PDF file. We need to send it a PDF file and it returns same with digital signature plus status messages.

Cheers!

Comment: No. You need to recompile on JDK 6.

Comment: @BoristheSpider sometimes it's too easy ;)

Comment: @BoristheSpider - If you're referring to java client then yes that's what I am doing.

Comment: Something is compiled in Java 7, `SignServ.java` for example. You can run older class files on newer JVMs but not the other way around.

Comment: So clearly this approach will not work and I realised that. Is there an alternative approach?